# Deserialize into same object using JsonConvert (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a method in my class that uses an API to get data. Next I use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to create another instance of the same class, then I copy the values to the object I'm in, which is where I wanted the values in the first place. Although this works just fine, it seems like there must be a better way to do this. (I know it could be further refactored for SRP. I'm just trying to find a more efficient way to get the values into the members.)

Can anyone show me a better way?

```
         public class MyModel
         {
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Last_Name { get; set; }
            public string Nickname { get; set; }


            public void Load()
            {
                var results = {code that gets stuff}
                MyModel item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(results.ToString());

                this.Description = item.Description;
                this.Last_Name = item.Last_Name;
                this.Nickname = item.Nickname;
            }
            .
            .
            .

         }
```

Comment: What is your original json? the model for deserialization? the model you really want to achive(the model you copy the values)? the code that does this? I think you have enough reps to ask a good question.....

Comment: I want the data that I retrieve from the api call to land in the members of this same object that made the call. This code does this, but I'm looking to see if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Nikita Read the code and tags. OP already uses it

Comment: @Kenny Your code doesn't make any sense. I already said how you can improve your question.... http://sscce.org/

Comment: Since item return as null until the deserialization process is complete, I don't think there's an easier way to do what you want to do.

Comment: The issue with this question is that it does not have one clear answer. There are myriad different ways to do any particular thing (like deserialze an object from an API call), but everyone is going to have different suggestions as to what is the "better way". And the true best way (if such a thing can exist) depends on many things outside of the scope of this question.

There really is no true better way that doesn't involve refactoring as you described. Any other way is just going to be deserializing and copying properties like you're doing already, just shuffled around.

Comment: One reason that the question is not clear enough is because I'm very new to C#. I'm sorry I can't put it more clearly. I appreciate the responses. I agree that there are multiple ways to solve it. I may not even be approaching it the right way. If I figure out a better way I'll post it here.

Comment: @Kenny I think Filip's answer below is your best bet without refactoring. It makes it such that the `Copy()` method doesn't have to change every time the Model does.

Comment: @EricSondergard I don't see what problem does below answer solve? It is all about how you design your project. Create an instance of an object by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` or create an empty instance and fill its properties in an instance method by `JsonConvert.PopulateObject`.

Comment: @Kenny `because I'm very new to C#`  Asking a good and compelete question  is not related with a knowledge of a programming language. You still haven't posted what I asked in my first comment....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this

```
class A
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Value { get; set; }

            public void Load()
            {
                var json = @"{Id:1,Value:""Value""}";
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That may be it. I'm not familiar with the PopulateObject method on JsonConvert. I will look it up tomorrow when I get back to work. Thank you.

Comment: But I would not really recommend doing it this way. A POCO object should not have logic in it just properties. You should have a look at [Repository pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-cplusdoneplusright)

Comment: That was in fact exactly what I was looking for! I just tested it and it worked. I will definitely look into the Repository pattern. I do want to architect this correctly, and I'm getting there little by little. I appreciate your help Filip.